# WSO2 API Manager: Fault message schema (xsd)

Tags: soap, xsd, wso2, wso2-api-manager, fault

WHat is the schema defintion of the fault message when a service on the WSO2 API Managers fails. For example the services has the status blocked, invoking this service, WSO2 replies with an proper SOAP-Fault message. What is the schema (xsd) defintition of the am:fault element?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://foobar.nl/foobar">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
         <am:code>700700</am:code>
         <am:message>API blocked</am:message>
         <am:description>This API has been blocked temporarily. Please try again later or contact the system administrators.</am:description>
      </am:fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

A documentation request is created to WSO2 to update the documentation; https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-866

Answer (score 0):

The default schema is,

```
  <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
     <am:code>ERROR_CODE</am:code>
     <am:message>ERROR_MESSAGE</am:message>
     <am:description>ERROR_DESCRIPTION</am:description>
  </am:fault>
```

You can customize the fault format through sequences.